# Why is my AWS database only connectable in the first few minutes?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services

I created MySQL database in RDS of AWS, and successfully connected it from MySQL workbench and Spring Boot application. However, it only works for the 10 to 20 minutes. Then, I can't connect to it anymore.

If I delete the database and create a new one, same problem will happen. It only works in the beginning. Although I haven't changed anything since I created the databases, it still stopped being connectable.

What can be possibly causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check the security group attached to RDS. If you specify a rule to access from specific IP address/address space. Maybe the IP has changed

Reference - [RDS Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html)

Comment: What should I change to the security group if i want to access the RDS next time?

Comment: When you create RDS from the wizard with default configuration it create SG with a rule to access the DB from public IP address your computer is using at that moment. Public IP your accessing can be changed time to time. 

Go to Security Groups you will find a security group like, group name  "rds-launch-wizard-1" see the inbound rules. you can see port 3306 allowed from specific public IP